# Photoshop CS4 variable relative path not working

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs4

In Adobe Photoshop CS4, I'm trying to use variables and data sets to dynamically replace images listed on a .csv file.

When I tried to use the relative path of the images, the program throws an error "Could not apply data set because the replacement file was not found"

But according to an article in the adobe [website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7417a.html), it should work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please add your code so we can we what you're working with

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this kind of errors comes from the fact that ExtendScript is struggling with backslashes. Makes sure you escape your paths before using them. Or convert them to forward slashes:

```
var cleanFilePath = myFilePath.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```